# Creating a new DOCX file by reading DOCX template (it's content is already replaced)

Tags: file, new-operator, docx

Up to now code is read the template and replace with new values and finally replace the docx file with new values. Can any one please tell me how to save the replaced docx file in diffrent name?.

My code is bellow.

```
   using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
        {
            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Regex regexText = new Regex("#ApplicationCompleteDate#");
            docText = regexText.Replace(docText,DataHolding.ApplicationCompleteDate);

            regexText = new Regex("#ApplicantPrivateAddress#");
            docText = regexText.Replace    (docText,UserDataHolding.ApplicantPrivateAddress);


       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream   (FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
            }
        }
```

If any one help me with this creating new docx file by changing above code, it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: The posted code is not rendered correctly. Please reformat your post. You may also want add a C# tag

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create))
    sw.Write(docText)
    sw.Close()
    sw.Dispose()
```